# Install RealVNC And Dependencies

Tags: vnc, headless

I have a minimal install on my Pi Zero using [DietPi](http://www.dietpi.com).

I now want to add RealVNC to it so I have followed the instructions at their site:
https://www.realvnc.com/docs/raspberry-pi.html

I installed it with `sudo apt-get install realvnc-vnc-server`

The I had to install some missing dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install xauth x11-xserver-utils libgtk2.0-0
```

Now I get an error in the log:

```
Starting session: /etc/X11/Xsession
Session terminated with return code 1
FreeFontPath: FPE "/usr/share/vnc/fonts/" refcount is 2, should be 1; fixing.
<13> 2016-12-05T05:14:35.436Z DietPi Xvnc[2932]: ServerManager: Server stopped
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":1"
  after 78 requests (78 known processed) with 29 events remaining.
```

Comment: Consult the DietPi ready-to-run applications using `dietpi-software list`. See the [this forum post](http://dietpi.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=5#p5) for reference. There is a RealVNC app, so you don't have to go the `apt-get` way.

Comment: 139 is not released yet.

Comment: Oops, missed that., sorry. But listed just above are some alternatives that are available. TightVNC Server, for example.

Comment: RealVNC is the only one that does Direct Capture

Comment: Ok, it says on the RealVNC page you referred to that for older or _other distributions_ than raspbian you should [install manually](https://www.realvnc.com/docs/raspberry-pi.html#raspberry-pi-legacy). If you installed with apt, you didn't go that route.

Comment: I'm not saying that the method _will_ work, just that it is prescribed by Real. You probably have an issue with the packages used by RealVNC, they might not be the right version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's installed ok if you're getting that far.

You're starting a virtual mode session but the Xsession script is failing to start a desktop environment, so it just shuts down immediately. By default it will run /etc/vnc/xstartup, which is supposed to start the default desktop environment and not return until the user logs off. You should make sure you have a suitable environment installed (e.g. LXDE).

Alternatively, you can run the RealVNC server in service mode, which lets you connect to the console display (i.e. what you see if you have a display plugged in). You can start this by starting/enabling the vncserver-x11-serviced service. This requires X11 to be running, unless you have enabled "experimental direct capture mode", in which case it can remote the text-mode console too - see this page for more details: https://www.realvnc.com/docs/raspberry-pi.html#running-directly-rendered-apps-such-as-minecraft-remotely